# CreateMutex and ActiveX

Tags: windows, winapi, activex, mutex

I'm developing an Internet Explorer ActiveX plugin using Qt, and trying to make the installer ensure the plugin is not running before continuing. A standard approach to this is to create a named mutex in the application and try to open it in the installer.

This works fine when built as a standalone .exe, but when the plugin DLL is loaded by either idc.exe (to register the server or handle the type library) or IE itself (after adding a test against argv[0] to skip CreateMutex for the idc runs), the CreateMutex call crashes.

Here's how I'm calling it:

CreateMutex((LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "mutex_name_here");

Is there a reason this should fail when run within the context of an ActiveX server, but work correctly when running standalone? Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Go easy on those casts.  They only let you shut up the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.  It didn't stop you from doing it wrong.

Comment: Yep. This is what I get for not understanding the function I'm using and taking a random Google result's word for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `CreateMutex()` is a pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure (which contains a pointer to a security descriptor); it's not a set of requested access rights bits, which is what you're passing in. I'm not sure why that would work any better in a standalone application.

You probably want to pass in NULL for the first parameters so the mutex gets created with a default security descriptor.

The Desired Access bits would get passed to `OpenMutex()`.

Comment: I see - that was taken from a Google result (we're using Qt threading primitives otherwise). Will a mutex with default security options be accessible from a different process?

Comment: The default access is derived from the token of the creator, so passing in NULL would permit access from any other process owned by the same user.